# Using colors from color.xml in java code

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Is there any way to call colors from colors.xml in java?
I have created an editor and i want use those colors which i have already defined in colors.xml from java
how can i do this ?

Comment: Do you mean getting color from xml resource. Something like this: `getResources().getColor(R.color.colorname)`?

Comment: getResources().getColor(R.color.colorname) working this thanks dude

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get a color as an int, use the following:

```
int myColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor);
```

Then, to use this color in a TextView, use the following:

```
myTextView.setTextColor(myColor);
```

Comment: glad I could help. To make sure this helps other people too, please don't forget to upvote / accept. thanks!

Comment: getColor is now deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
 getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set the textcolor to your textview:

myTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));